# Inserting Long Binary data into Access db using pyodbc

Tags: sql, ms-access, python-2.7, pyodbc

I can insert text and integer data to MS Access db (.mdb) by using pyodbc package. But now i want to insert Large Binary objects. I have a table that consists ID(COUNTER type), Name(VARCHAR type), File (LONGBINARY type), Author(VARCHAR type) columns. I use that code to insert some text and int data:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table(ID, Name) VALUES(1,'book')""")
```

After that i used that code but always getting error.

```
with open('c:/tree.jpg', 'rb') as file:
      binData = file.read()

SQL = """INSERT INTO table VALUES(2,'threePicture', %s, 'Mike')""" %(binData)

cursor.execute(SQL)
```

The error is: **ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000])**

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using ? ? ? characters...

```
cursor.execute("insert into table values(?, ?, ?, ?)", 2, 'treePicture', pyodbc.Binary(binData), 'Mike')
```

**Use ? chars for values in expression.**